# Convert oracle time string to time.Time golang

Tags: go

I am new to golang and trying to convert string date received from oracle DB into time.Time in golang.

Here is the plaground link: https://play.golang.org/p/z3OyC4-DTFA

```
timeTest, err := time.Parse("22-JAN-06", "26-JAN-17")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("\n\npaymentDateAfter: %v\n\n", timeTest)
} else {
    fmt.Printf("\n\npaymentDateErr: %v\n\n", err)
}
```

Can anybody help me understand the issue. I tried searching it and found many answers in stack overflow, but none of them for this format.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in [the docs](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Parse), the `layout` time in `time.Parse` needs to represent the following year/month/day/etc...: `Mon Jan 2 15:04:05 -0700 MST 2006`

However, you are using `Jan 22 2006`.

If you change your code to the following, it works:

```
func main() {
    test, err := time.Parse("2-Jan-2006", "26-MAR-2018")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(test)
    // Prints: 2018-03-26 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
}
```

**Note**: the month (`Jan`) in the layout is case sensitive, but the month (`MAR`) in the string to be parsed is case insensitive.

Comment: How about if the date is "2-JAN-06", do note the month is in all caps

Comment: It works too, the matching is case insensitive, I've updated the answer. Note that the layout string is still `Jan`